# Java - Creating a Paginated List

Tags: java, pagination

I need to create a class which acts as a paginated list. My use case is like this:

I am writing a library which makes a service call to fetch a `List<obj>`. Since the `List<>` can be large, the service expects me to call with a `PAGE_SIZE`. The service has also provided me with a TPS of `x` which I need call it with.

I need to do two things:

- Rate Limit my calls to the Service
- Expose a PaginatedList<> from the library so that any client can use the Library and rate limit as per their TPS.

I was wondering whether the way I am implementing this PaginatedList is correct or if there is a better way.

```
public MyPaginatedList {
  private static final PAGE_SIZE = 50;
  private ServiceClient client;
  private int pageToProcess = 0; //to keep track of which page we need to process next
  private List<Data> data; // this is what the library exposes to outside world
  public MyPaginatedList(ServiceClient client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public MyPaginatedList getDataList(){
    Servicerequest request = new ServiceRequest();
    request.setIndex(PAGE_SIZE*pageToProcess++); // fetch the next set of items

    this.data = client.APICall(request);
    return this; // we return the current object
  }
}
```

The public API exposed by this Library would use `MyPaginatedList` like this:

```
class Library {
  private ServiceClient client;

  public Library(ServiceClient client) {
    this.client = client;
  }
  public MyPaginatedList fetchData() {
    return new MyPaginatedList(client).getDataList();
  }
}
```

Any client of this library can use `MyPaginatedList` and make **Rate Limited Calls** like this.

> ```
> MyPaginatedList resultData = new Library().fetchData();
> while(true) {
>   for(Data d: resultData.getData()) // loop over the list exposed by MyPaginatedlist
>   ...
>   }
>   RateLimiter.acquire(); // use guava rate limiter, would block till a token is available
>   resultData = resultData.getDataList();
>   if(resultData.getData().isempty()) {
>     break;
>   }
> }
> ```

**Edit:-**

3 straightforward approaches come to my mind -

> 1. The one described above. Where the `PaginatedList would expose a way to fetch next pages (batch of elements or List<>)`
> 2. Let the Library expose 2 API's -
>
>    `PaginatedList fetchData()` -> client would call this one initially
>      `PaginatedList fetchNextPage(PaginatedList)` -> client would call this
>      for sub-sequent pages
> 3. This one is slightly modified version of approach 2. Let library expose a modified `fetchData()`
>
>    `PaginatedList fetchData(PaginatedList list)` -> initially client
>      would need to create a `new PaginatedList()`, which would initialize
>      it's state like `pageToProcess = 0;` This API kind of takes in the
>      metadata associated with the service call to identify which page to
>      get next

Any more suggestions or variations would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 1):

spring has the concept of paging and they do something like this:

```
public Page findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

where the Page interface has the following methods (trimmed):

```
getTotalElements()
getTotalPages()
isFirst()
isLast()
nextPageable()
previousPageable()
```

it also extends the iterable interface so you can loop like this:

```
Library library = new Library();
Pageable pageRequest = ...
Page<T> page;
do {
  page = library.getData(pageRequest);
  for (T t: page) {
    log.debug("T is {}", t);
  }
  pageRequest = page.nextPageable();
} while( !page.isLast() );
```

the most notable difference is that the page being requested is not stored as a state in the client library. by storing the state you make it harder to use the same instance from multiple places in the code.

see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/paging-chapter.html

Comment: I think the same Library Instance is still usable in different places, since the fetchData() method returns a new instance of PaginatedList. The reason I kept the List<> in the PaginatedList is to enable the client to call the getter() on it & retrieve the same List<>.